# Grails if checks html select value

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails

I have a problem with checking the select/grails select tag value via grails if tag. My code looks like this,
html:

```
<select id="select1" name="select1">
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
</select>
```

or grails select:

```
<g:select id="select1" name="select1" from="${[2, 3] }" value="2"/>
```

and the grails if:

```
...
<g:each var="rowNumber" in = "${0..5}">
    <g:if test="${rowNumber} < ${select1.value}"> <!-- or ${select1.val()} or select1.value --> 
        ...
    </g:if>
</g:each>...
```

Code throws an NullPointerException, and says that select1 is a null object and he cannot evaluate method val(), or cannot get attribute value.
Anyone have an idea what I should do to fix this problem?
Thanks for help!

## EDIT

Inside my if statement I have a render template, and when I change the value of select I want to render this templates again, but with saving what I have already type there (e.g if I have a textfield in my template).

## EDIT2

I messed up a little bit. I want to create a dynamic table, e.g at start it could have 2 rows & columns, then I want to be able to enlarge/decreasenumber of rows/columns (e.g. by clicking button/buttons) of course by clicking the button, I want to save already filled table in ajax, then render table with new number of rows/columns, and fill earlier filled cell with their previous values (new cells will be empty).
e.g.
filled table 2x2

```
a a
a a
```

when I enlarge this table to 3x2 I want the table looks like this:

```
a a
a a
_ _
```

where _ is an empty cell.

Comment: You cannot access `select1` in your GSP since it runs on the server side and `select1` actually lives in a browser. Means your approach is wrong. But if you could explain what you are trying to achieve we maybe can provide you a working approach.

Comment: #saw303 I want to dynamically check if the actual selected value is greater than my variable in foreach loop, and depends on the result render views. I tried use js function instead but it tolds me that the method is undefined.

Here is my code:
...
    <g:if test="${checkRows(rowNumber) }">
...

js:

    function checkRows(rowNumber)
    {
        var elem = document.getElementById('rowsNumberSelect').val();
        if(rowNumber < elem)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: Where do you want to perform this check? On the client-side (the browser) or on the server-side (your Grails controller)? Currently you mix `Javascript` (client-side) with `tag libraries` (server-side)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to work on the client side you need to work with `Javascript` only.

```
function checkRows(rowNumber) 
{ 
    var value= $('#select1').val(); 
    return rowNumber < elem;
}
```

If you want to trigger the function when the select value changes use

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $('#select1').change(function() {
       checkRows(34 /* use your value here */);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for. Inside my if statement I have a render template, and when I change the value of select I want to render this templates again, but with saving what I have already type there (e.g if I have a textfield in my template).

Comment: Okay. But that means you need to do this on the server-side. Please provide your complete view and describe your use case as clearly as possible.

Comment: #saw303 I messed up a little bit. I want to create a dynamic table, e.g at start it could have 2 rows & columns, then I want to be able to enlarge/decreasenumber of rows/columns (e.g. by clicking button/buttons) of course by clicking the button, I want to save already filled table in ajax, then render table with new number of rows/columns, and fill earlier filled cell with their previous values (new cells will be empty).
e.g.
filled table 2x2
a a
a a
when I enlarge this table to 3x2 I want the table looks like this:
a a
a a
_ _

where _ is an empty cell.